# NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system when load .pkl file in prod environtment

Tags: python, pandas

I try to load a pickle file that initially saved from 'nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")' it sucess to load and use in jupyter notebopok, but NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system when load .pkl file in prod environtment

This is what I've done:

1. changing path to backslash

But, the error still similar, do you have any idea?

Comment: Sounds like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68796747/6699447) is related.